# Why would Type.GetType return null with telerik types in sitefinity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitefinity-4

I have set up a widget for the backend of my Sitefinity site that has three textboxes and a button.  The goal is to create a new column in the database:

```
    protected void btnAddClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Type TelerikType = Type.GetType(txtTelType.Text);
        Type ColumnType = Type.GetType(txtColType.Text);
        string error = "";
        if (TelerikType == null)
        {
            error = "Telerik Type is invalid";
        }
        if (ColumnType == null)
        {
            error = "Column Type is invalid";
        }
        if (error.Length == 0)
        {
            App.WorkWith()
              .DynamicData()
              .Type(TelerikType)
              .Field()
                   .TryCreateNew(txtName.Text, ColumnType)
                   .SaveChanges(true);
            error = "Added column successfully";
            txtColType.Text = txtName.Text = txtTelType.Text = "";
        }
        literalErrorText.Text = string.Format(literalErrorText.Text, error);

    }
```

I am having two problems:

1. When I enter Telerik.Sitefinity.Pages.Model.PageNode into the textbox, Type.GetType(txtTelType.Text) is returning null.
2. If I replace that portion with typeof(PageNode) I get "Specified type 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Pages.Model.PageNode' is not a dynamic type."

I'm hoping somebody might have some insight as to why these things wouldn't work correctly, or possibly a better way to approach this issue? For reference, my goal (at least for now) is to add a dynamic column that references PageNode so that I can specify a ShowInLeftNavigation boolean and a ShowInRightNavigation boolean. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: question does Telerik control that you are checking resolve to a string..? if so can you do the if statement if (TelerikType == string.isEmptyOrNull)  ..?

Comment: it's better to check Objects using the Equals key word and when checking if int a= 5; b int = 6 if you want to check if values or value types equal something use the " =="

Comment: TelerikType is of type Type.  also, wouldn't I get an null reference exception if i try to use .Equals with a null object?

Comment: Object if not assigned by default are null so doing a null check of will not give reference exception.. usually that happens if you try to access an object without initializing its prop or fiels or if you do not new the object you can do StringBuilder stb = default; in .net 4.0 and it will be null if you debug and check it's value .. as well as if you check for example if(stb == null) will return true. or doing the same with the .Equals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the docs carefully [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx):

> typeName Type: System.String 
>   The **assembly-qualified name** of the type
>   to get. See [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx). If the type is in the currently
>   executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the
>   type name qualified by its namespace.

So if the type is not one of the base .Net types, or in the currently executing assembly, you have to tell GetType what assembly to look in as well.
I don't know what assembly the Telerik control are in, but it looks like you will have to add the assembly to the type name, something linke this:

> TopNamespace.SubNameSpace.ContainingClass, MyAssembly,
>   Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b17a5c561934e089

Follow the link for "AssemblyQualifiedName" above to get all the gory details of the syntax.

Comment: Thanks, got the assembly qualified name like this :  typeof(Telerik.Sitefinity.Pages.Model.PageNode).AssemblyQualifiedName; Any ideas why pagenode wouldn't be considered a dynamic type? do i need to use pages?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Type.GetType doesn't that check for Object type
```

for example System.String ect... can you try replacing the = null with

```
if (TelerikType.Equals(null))
```

Comment: Yeah, if(TelerikType.Equals(null)) results in "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when TelerikType is null.  But the issue here is that it shouldn't be null because the type exists.. the code responds as expected when TelerikType is null

Comment: are you creating an instance of the Type Type TelerikType = typeof(txtTelType); I wonder if this will be able to accept the ObjectType this way..I don't have Telerik on my local pc here I do however have it on my personal pc at home :( GRR

Comment: the idea is to convert a string into a type...  for instance, typeof(String) returns the same thing as Type.GetType("System.String"). typeof("System.String") won't compile because no overloads match.

Comment: are you wanting to check the value of that string.. ? the Telerik type will return you want type Telerik control inherits from..